# Is it possible to import and use a react-redux component from vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two applications, one of them is written in vanilla javascript with html and css. The other one is a react + redux application.

Is it possible to import and use the components from my react + redux application inside my vanilla javascript application without introducing a dependency on react and redux?

Comment: you can import the reducer, and call as a normal function

Comment: you'll need to define "use".

Comment: @DanO Will I be able to import my react component (which is connected to a redux store) and render it (and actually use it, click buttons inside it which interact with the store) inside my vanilla JS app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, **yes** , depending how you've written the code. Namely, assuming you are using ES6 Modules, or using a transpiler that will handle them as such.

Firstly, remember that react-redux is just an implementation of redux for react. Redux works fine by itself.

Assuming what you are talking about is reusing your reducers and action creators, then that will be fine - as all they are are pure functions.

For example say your app looks like:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react"; 
import store from "./store";
import {createUser} from "./actions"; 
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

//etc.
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

    export default function() {
        return createStore(rootReducer); 
    }
```

**actions.js**

```
   export  function addUser(name) {
       return {
            type: "ADD_USER", 
            payload: name, 
       }
   }
```

**reducers.js**

```
   export default function (state ={}, action)  {

        return {
            value: action.payload
        }
    }
```

In this scenario, lets say you want to reuse the action, and the reducer.

Then you can just import the functions from these modules. ESM modules are smart enough to just import what they need.

On the otherhand, say you were importing the `createStore` (default) method, then you would also be importing the dependency on redux.

Comment: Minor clarification (not that it will have a big effect on your answer), I didn't mean I was using the react-redux library I just meant I was using react and redux in my application. Also, would you be able to give me an example where the answer would be no and I wouldn't be able to use my components from my vanilla javascript? I think it would help my understanding a lot more.